# How can I clear all EIGRP routes?

Tags: routing, eigrp

Working through [NetSim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_simulation#List_of_network_simulators), I graded my work and found that at first I put the wrong IP address in the [EIGRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Interior_Gateway_Routing_Protocol) routing table, so I then tried adding the write one.

I then tried to grade my work again, and realized it doesn’t remove a previous route; it just adds one. So right now I have multiple IP addresses in the routing table, and I've tried issuing commands to remove them without any luck. Some commands I tried using to solve this:

```
Core# show running-config

router eigrp 100

network 20.1.1.0 0.0.0.3
network 20.1.1.4 0.0.0.3
network 20.1.1.12 0.0.0.3
network 192.168.10.0
network 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
```

The solution is

```
router eigrp 100
network 20.1.1.0 0.0.0.3
network 20.1.1.4 0.0.0.3
network 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
```

I then tried to run a `clear ip route 20.1.1.12 0.0.0.3*`, and I got an error code.

Is there a way to simply clear the entire routing table and just enter them in again?

Comment: Can you try "router eigrp 100" then "no network 20.1.1.0 0.0.0.3" 
Or "no router eigrp 100 network 20.1.1.0 0.0.0.3"

Comment: Be clear that such a network statement does not add the network into your routing table. That is a common mistake people make. The network statement is telling the routing protocol which interface(s) to include in its process, not which networks to install in the routing table. BGP is an exception, telling BGP which networks to advertise, but only if they already exist in the routing table.

Answer (score 3):

To remove an individual network statement, you can type:

```
router eigrp 100
no network 20.1.1.0 0.0.0.3
```

There's no command to remove all network statements.  You could try removing the entire routing function by typing

```
no router eigrp 100
```

and re-entering all the configuration.

BTW, the `network` statement in eigrp is not a route.  It tells the router which interfaces belong in the eigrp domain.

Comment: 'no router eigrp 100' worked ! thank you ! Also, thanks for clearing that up ! Its been a bit confusing understanding EIGRP

Comment: @ruckus_telecom consider marking the answer as accepted so it doesn't keep popping up as unanswered.